# Angular 1.3 error: Argument 'PageNavController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I have a question about my Angular 1.3 and Django Project.

Background:  I am writing a web application using Django Frameworks and Angular 1.3 for the front end.  The short term goal is to simply use angular to be able to change views using a controller.  I'll show the code for the angular application I am using in my project:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';


  angular
    .module('viex', [
      'viex.config',
      'viex.routes',
      'viex.authentication',
      'viex.layout',
      etc...


    ]);

  angular
    .module('viex.config', []);

  angular
    .module('viex.routes', ['ngRoute']);


  angular
  .module('viex')
  .run(run);

run.$inject = ['$http'];

function run($http) {
  $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
  $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
}
})();
```

Here are some of my routes.  Ignore the ones that render templates...those work just fine.  I am attempting to use a URL with an action, so when someone types /welcome, an action of welcome.view will occur.  Here is the code:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';


  angular.module('viex.routes').config(config);

  config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

  function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      controller: 'PageNavController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    }).when('/welcome', {
      action: 'welcome.view'
    }).when('/faq', {
      action: 'faq.view'
    }).when('/browse', {
      templateUrl: 'static/templates/layout/browse.html'
    }).when('/termsandconditions', {
      controller: '',
      controllerAs: '',
      templateUrl: 'static/templates/toc/termsandconditions.html'
    .otherwise('/');
  }



})();
```

Next, I define a module for my layout which in turn contain my controllers:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('viex.layout', [
      'viex.layout.controllers'
    ]);

  angular
    .module('viex.layout.controllers', []);
})();
```

Lastly, the controller I want to use to change my views (not serve templates, but simply hide and show certain elements).

```
/**
* PageNavController
* @namespace viex.layout.controllers
*/
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('viex.layout.controllers')
    .controller('PageNavController', PageNavController);

  PageNavController.$inject = ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams'];

  /**
  * @namespace PageNavController
  */
  function PageNavController( $scope, $route, $routeParams ) {

        render = function(){

            var renderAction = $route.current.action;

            console.log(renderAction);
            var renderPath = renderAction.split(".");

            var username = ($routeParams.username || "");

            var isWelcome = (renderPath[ 0 ] == "welcome");
            var isFaq = (renderPath[ 0 ] == "faq");

            $scope.renderAction = renderAction;
            $scope.renderPath = renderPath;

            $scope.username = username;

            $scope.isWelcome = isWelcome;
            $scope.isFaq = isFaq;

        };

        $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess",
            function( $currentRoute, $previousRoute ){
                render();
            }
        );

  }

})();
```

All I want to do is Switch from one view to another using the controller above.  When A view is rendered, only one will show, and the others will hide for this simplistic example.   Here is the HTML:

```
<div  ng-app="viex" ng-controller="PageNavController">
            {% include 'navbar.html' %}

                        <div ng-switch on="renderPath[ 0 ]">

                        <div ng-switch-when="welcome">

                            {% include 'welcome.html'%}
                        </div>

                        <div ng-switch-when="faq">
                            {% include 'faq.html' %}
                        </div>
                </div>
        {% include 'footer.html'%}
</div>
```

When I load my page, I get the error "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'PageNavController' is not a function, got undefined".  My line of thinking was that I made my function PageNavController in my controller.  Evidently, my application doesn't recognize it, or my syntax is messed up.

I am using Angular 1.3+, Python 3.X, and Django 1.8+.

Thanks again to anyone who can offer some help or point me in the right direction where to start looking!

-DJ

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't support namespace even you name the modules in that style. You have to inject viex.layout.controllers into your viex.routes module.

```
angular
.module('viex.routes', ['ngRoute',  'viex.layout.controllers']);
```